# Is there a way to access host in a component implementing ControlValueAccessor?

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, model, controlvalueaccessor

By host, I understand the scope of where my component is used. If it is defined as `<my-component>`, then if it’s used somewhere as:

`<my-component name=“Test” class=“test-class” #test=“ngModel” [(ngModel)]=“data.test” required>`

then I would like to:

- know if host component has a certain css class (i.e. test-class) applied to it.
- get all the validators that are applied to the ngModel there (i.e. RequiredValidator)
- know if form that ngModel belongs to has been submitted (without introducing own custom property)

For some reason, I couldn’t get to it reliably. I know of:

- HostBinding, but that is sadly one way only and can apply classes on host, but is not updated with regards to what classes already are there
- ElementRef injection, where I can get to nativeElement and props. That gives me classes (but very low level), but not validators / ngModel.

Is the access to ngModel “above” on the host element not allowed here?

Comment: You can find answers here:
https://medium.com/p/d51dc16c0c3c

https://medium.com/p/b7f09a485fba

Comment: Ah, the old delayed Injector trick! Thanks, this is very helpful, I’ll try this out. Any hint for detecting a class on host?

Comment: You can try as you described with nativeElement, or maybe it's a way to use @Attribute('class') decorator injection.

Comment: @Attribute is not binding, just a static property read upon initialization.